# Number equations in pandoc by default

Tags: equations, numbering, pandoc

How to get equations written in `$$...$$` numbered when markdown document is compiled to PDF file.

I do not need to make references for equations.

Comment: Do you need to use the `$$...$$` setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [pandoc-eqnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos) filter.  You can install pandoc-eqnos as root using the bash command

```
pip install pandoc-eqnos
```

To tag an equation with the label `eq:description`, use

```
$$ y = mx + b $$ {#eq:description}
```

The prefix `#eq:` is required whereas `description` can be replaced with any combination of letters, numbers, dashes, slashes and underscores.  If you don't need to reference the equation, then just leave the `description` part out.

In case others are wondering, to reference the equation, use

```
@eq:description
```

To apply the filter, use the following option with pandoc:

```
--filter pandoc-eqnos
```

Full details and demos are given on the [pandoc-eqnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos) Web page at github.

Comment: This hasn't worked. It still renders the equation reference as text.

Answer (score 3):

If you write `(@) $1+1=2$` it will be numbered. You can label and refer by writing `(@foo)`. See the section 'Numbered example lists' in the Pandoc User's Guide for more information.

Pandoc writes the following to the .tex file:

`\begin{enumerate}

\def\labelenumi{(\arabic{enumi})}

\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt

\item

  $1 + 1 = 2$

\end{enumerate}`

Comment: I want the number to be placed to the right

Comment: That might well be possible by doing something to the enumerate environment. (But a bit of searching hasn't turned up an obvious answer.)

Answer (score 1):

When using Pandoc to get PDF outputs, it goes through Latex. Using the following gets numbered equations by default:

```
\begin{align}
x=y
\end{align}
```

But you'll have to be willing to give up using the `$$` marker for an equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @MartinSchröder I am not sure how I can improve the format of the answer, but feel free to use the "edit" to improve it by all means. (Also, I actually used my registered user account, thanks!)